# Determine if one Map is a subset of another Map

Tags: flutter, collections, dart, subset, combinatorics

I found that `package:collection/collection.dart` can be used to determine if two `Map`'s are equal, but I can't find any method to determine if one of them is a subset of the other one. For example, if I have the following `Map`

```
{
    'a': 'b',
    'c': [1,2,3],
    'd': 4  
}
```

The following are valid subsets:

```
{ 'a': 'b' }
{ 'c': [1,2,3] }
{ 'd': 4 }

{ 
    'a': 'b',
    'c': [1,2,3]
}

{
    'a': 'b',
    'd': 4  
}

{
    'c': [1,2,3],
    'd': 4  
}
```

But the following are not valid subsets:

```
{ 'a': 'x' }

{ 
    'a': 'b',
    'c': [1,2,99]
}
```

How can I test this in Dart (Flutter)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get each `MapEntry` of subset candidate and check if original map contains the same value. If value is a collection, then it has to be compared using `DeepCollectionEquality`.

Here is my code:

```dart
import 'package:collection/collection.dart'; // import for DeepCollectionEquality

bool isSubset(Map map, Map subsetCandidate) {
  return subsetCandidate.entries.every(
      (entry) => DeepCollectionEquality().equals(entry.value, map[entry.key]));
}
```

Comment: I've only tested a few cases, but so far it seems to work perfectly.